# Can Parse.com analytics show a graph of the values of a key in a class, instead of the plain requests?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new to the whole thing of cloud and i was wondering, using the services of Parse.com Analytics, if i can keep track of the values of a key in a class, that changes constantly.
To be more specific, i send the number of the steps a android phone user makes, every time the locationManager gets an update of a new location change, using a ParseObject of the name "distValues" and having this code at the end of the method MyLocationListener:

```
distValues.put("Step", step);               
            distValues.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alert_dialog_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alert_dialog_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }

        });
```

The Analytics graph of the dashboard shows the request that this ParseObject writes to the appropriate key and that's it. So, i created a Map varialbe by the name "dimensions" as like as in the documentation (https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#analytics-custom) and under a metadata pack name of "Values"

```
ParseAnalytics.trackEvent("Values",dimensions);
```

I keep track of the steps

```
dimensions.put("step",Integer.toString(step));
```

Parse Analytics gives me the option to breakdown the "Value" track event, to show me the item "step" how many requests have made. Problem is, that i would like to see the number of steps in a graph at a given time, not the number of requests to write to the key "step".
Is there a way to do this?
Is Parse the right tool to do this, or i missed the whole idea of their cloud backend?
Apart of Google's App Engine or Fusion Tables, are there any backends that can do this task?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Parse Analytics is a very basic app/server analysis tool and is focused on app performance, data volume and custom events analysis. It is not intended for the analysis of the data you store with Parse.

And since the Parse.com backend won't be available anymore from January 28, 2017 it may be advisable to start looking for a data analysis solution elsewhere that fits your needs.

Regarding the self-hosted open source Parse Server you should know that it doesn't provide any analytics functionality so far.